# Why imported hook gives an error has already been declared

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, confirm-dialog

In my react project, I import this:

```
import confirmDialog from '../../components/confirmDialog/ConfirmDialog';
```

when I add the bottom line:

```
const [confirmDialog, SetConfirmDialog] = useState ({isOpen: false, title: '', subTitle: ''});
```

I get the following error:
`Identifier 'confirmDialog' has already been declared`.

also i used `confirmDialog` in MyComponet like this:

```js
<ConfirmDialog
        ConfirmDialog={confirmDialog}
        SetConfirmDialog={SetConfirmDialog}
      />
```

Comment: You first import something as x and then declare local variable x. That makes two x in scope. First is a component, second is its state. My guess is that the first could be capitalized, import ConfirmDialog ...

Comment: Also, don't capitalize your local variable. It will make people confused about what they see, same for props. Follow the javascript convention of naming to make your code more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are re-declaring your imported component.
you can fix this issue by editing the name of your variables

```
import ConfirmDialog from '../../components/confirmDialog/ConfirmDialog';
...

const [confirmDialogContent, SetConfirmDialogContent] = useState ({isOpen: false, title: '', subTitle: ''});

...

<ConfirmDialog
        ConfirmDialog={confirmDialogContent}
        SetConfirmDialog={SetConfirmDialogContent}
      />
```